# Issue while executing the PL/SQL conditional statements

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I try update few table ebtries based on another table column value, I am facing the following issue.

PL/SQL Query:

```
DECLARE
   buildVal NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT BUILDVERSION 
    INTO buildVal 
    FROM WCSDBA.BUILDDETAILS
    WHERE BUILDID =1;
    IF (buildVal = 0) THEN 
        UPDATE WCSDBA.BUILDDETAILS 
            set BUILDVERSION = 1, 
                BUILDDESCRIPTION = 'FirstVersion' 
            WHERE BUILDID =1;
        commit;
    END IF;
END;
```

Exception:

```
Query failed because: 
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

Any help or suggestions on the same

Comment: I think various revisions and edits may have lost the original error and its line number. You originally got syntax errors for the stray `AND` in the middle of the second update, and the missing `;` after `END IF`. Both of those have now gone and line 9 is the `UPDATE`. Can you confirm the current error message and line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE
   buildVal NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT BUILDVERSION INTO buildVal FROM WCSDBA.BUILDDETAILS WHERE BUILDID =1;
    IF (buildVal = 0) THEN 
        UPDATE WCSDBA.student set stVersion =1;
        UPDATE WCSDBA.BUILDDETAILS set BUILDVERSION = 1, BUILDDESCRIPTION = 'FirstVersion' WHERE BUILDID =1; --in this line
        commit;
    END IF; -- here
END;
```

Try this one please, you forgot the semi colon after `END IF` and separated update columns by `and` instead of comma

Comment: Tried your suggestions and still I am getting an issue. Updated the query and exception as well in the question. Did I miss any thing else

Comment: @SQLLearner Are you sure that you are correctly connected to the database? because when I run this script in my db, I don't get any exceptions about syntax, only the one that says that I do not have those tables, meaning that syntax is OK